# Why is the result of "decltype(i+j)" not an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, decltype, rvalue

I'm trying to come up a simple example for an operation that results in a rvalue.

This test case should have worked, but surprisingly (to me), the result of adding two `int`s is not an rvalue (reference). What am I missing here?

```
void test(int i, int j)
{
    // this assert should pass, but fails:
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i + j), int&&>(), "i + j should be a rvalue"); 
    // this assert passed, but should fail:
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i + j), int>(), "this assert should fail...");
}
```

Comment: It's just Plain Old Data. I don't think you can std::move an int..

Comment: This has always been int, since time immemorial (a.k.a. first Unixes). How would you move `2+2`?

Comment: You can very much `std::move` an `int` and that's besides the point anyway, the OP is asking about the value category of `i + j`.

Comment: Being an rvalue is not the same as being an rvalue reference.

Comment: `i+j` is an rvalue

Comment: @M.M right, I understood that from the accepted answer. Basically I was using `decltype` wrong. I'll see if I can improve the title to match my actual *problem*, not *what I was observing*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`i + j` is a [prvalue expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue_.28until_C.2B.2B11.29prvalue_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29),

> A prvalue ("pure rvalue") expression is an expression that does not have identity and can be moved from.
>
> a + b, a % b, a & b, a << b, and all other built-in arithmetic expressions;

not a [xvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue),

> An xvalue ("expiring value") expression is an expression that has identity and can be moved from.

And [decltype specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields `T` for prvalue, not `T&&`.

> a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields T&&;
> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields T&;
> c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype yields T.

You can make it xvalue by `std::move`:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::move(i + j)), int&&>(), "std::move(i + j) is a xvalue then this static_assert won't fail");
```

Comment: The paragraph about `decltype` is what I missed in the more general case. (Or, more generally speaking, the difference between the *value categories* and what *references they bind to*.) Thank you!

Comment: I clarified the question a bit now that I know what I got wrong. The difference is basically *is a rvalue* vs *binds to a rvalue reference*. I was expecting to check the second one, but did something else. Would you want to add that to your answer, or should I write my own self-accepted answer? (Since that would be the solution of my actual problem.)

Comment: @anderas I think it's fine to write your answer, based on your own aspect and understanding.

Comment: Done! Not sure which answer should be the accepted one, though. Yours answers the question *as written*, while mine answers the underlying problem.

Comment: @anderas Fine, it's up to you, op.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @songyuanyao's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762992/3198247), I noticed that my mistake was checking the wrong thing: My intention was to check whether the result of `i+j` would **bind to** a rvalue reference, but I checked whether it **is** a rvalue reference.

[decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)  deduces the type based on the **[value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)**, not based on what **[reference type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)** the value would *bind to*:

> 1) if the value category of expression is `xvalue`, then decltype yields `T&&`;
>   2) if the value category of expression is `lvalue`, then decltype yields `T&`;
>   3) if the value category of expression is `prvalue`, then decltype yields `T`.

As shown in the list, **since C++11, `rvalues` don't exist as a distinct category on the lowest level.** They are now a composite category containing both `prvalues` as well as `xvalues`. The question as written asks whether the expression is a `rvalue reference` and checks whether it is an `xvalue`.

From the list above, it is clear that `i+j` is a `prvalue`, so the third case applies. This explains why `decltype(i + j)` is `int` and not `int&&`.  Both `xvalues`and `prvalues` *bind to* rvalue references.

So by checking for whether `i+j` binds to a `lvalue reference` or a `rvalue reference` confirms that, indeed, it *binds to* a `rvalue reference`:

```
void foo(const int& f)
{
    std::cout << "binds to lvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

void foo(int&& f)
{
    std::cout << "binds to rvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

void test(int i, int j)
{
    foo(i); // lvalue -> lvalue ref

    foo(std::move(i)); // xvalue -> rvalue ref 
    // (std::move converts the argument to a rvalue reference and returns it as an xvalue)

    foo(i + j); // prvalue -> rvalue ref
}
```

**In conclusion:** `i+j` is **not** a rvalue reference, but it **binds to** one.

Comment: Can you make an example that is able to fetch all three types?

Comment: @Chiel, no, and that is the point that I tried to make with the distinction between the *category* and *what a value binds to*: There are only `rvalue` and `lvalue` references (not `xvalue`, `lvalue` and `prvalue` references). `prvalues` AND `xvalues` bind to rvalue references.

Comment: @Chiel unless you wanted me to show what values of these categories bind to. I added that to the sample.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me exactly what the `std::move` does here and what that means to `i`?

Comment: @Chiel in this case, `std::move` does the same thing as always: It casts the argument to a rvalue reference and returns it as an `xvalue` (which in turn binds to a rvalue reference, causing the `int&&` overload to be selected.

Comment: "In the new standard, there are no rvalues per se," - huh? You claim rvalues are being removed from C++17?

Comment: @M.M what was called `rvalue` in C++ before C++11 is now a `prvalue`. `rvalue`s still exist, but not as a distinct value category. They are a now a set that contains `prvalue`s and `xvalue`s. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: Yes, so there are rvalues. `i + j` is an rvalue.  (It's also a prvalue, but that doesn't mean it isn't an rvalue).

Comment: Right, but it being an rvalue doesn't mean it is automatically a prvalue. (The implication would work the other way around.) I hope the revision made clear what I meant to say.

Comment: Not really, it still says "there are no rvalues per se" which is false.  rvalue is one of the 5 value categories (which happens to overlap with other categories).

Comment: We wouldn't say "there are no numbers per se" just because the categories "even number" and "odd number" exist